# Can I use one .mdf file in multiple projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mdf

I have a project PROJECT_A which contains mdf file database.
In the solution of this project I added one new project - PROJECT_B.

My question is:Can I use .mdf file from PROJECT_A in PROJECT_B?

Comment: Did you try doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add .mdf file as a [Link Reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234) to project B

Right click project B and then properties > Add Reference > Existing Item > Select the .mdf file and in the add button select `Add As Link` option.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can  use single .mdf file in multiple projects. However it is not recommended since it may cause 'access denied' error. It is also a bad practice. You should be using per .mdf file per project/application.